# Fundir dinamicamente linhas que partilham a mesma chave numa só

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Eu tenho [um Dataframe](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RZTL9iEVW2uqepZVNPkJ5vt-IXzv66md/view?usp=sharing). Gostaria de fazer outra coluna que combine as colunas cujo nome começa com o mesmo valor em Answer e QID.

Ou seja, com este exercício do Dataframe:

```
    QID     Category    Text    QType   Question    Answer0     Answer1
0   16  Automotive  Access to car   Single  Do you have access to a car?    I own a car/cars    I own a car/cars
1   16  Automotive  Access to car   Single  Do you have access to a car?    I lease/ have a company car     I lease/have a company car
2   16  Automotive  Access to car   Single  Do you have access to a car?    I have access to a car/cars     I have access to a car/cars
3   16  Automotive  Access to car   Single  Do you have access to a car?    No, I don’t have access to a car/cars   No, I don't have access to a car
4   16  Automotive  Access to car   Single  Do you have access to a car?    Prefer not to say   Prefer not to say
5   17  Automotive  Make of car/cars    Multiple    If you own/lease a car(s), which brand are they?    Audi    Audi
6   17  Automotive  Make of car/cars    Multiple    If you own/lease a car(s), which brand are they?    Alfa Romeo  Alfa Romeo
7   17  Automotive  Make of car/cars    Multiple    If you own/lease a car(s), which brand are they?    BMW     BMW
8   17  Automotive  Make of car/cars    Multiple    If you own/lease a car(s), which brand are they?    Cadillac    Cadillac
9   17  Automotive  Make of car/cars    Multiple    If you own/lease a car(s), which brand are they?    Chevrolet   Chevrolet
10  17  Automotive  Make of car/cars    Multiple    If you own/lease a car(s), which brand are they?    Chrysler    Chrysler
11  17  Automotive  Make of car/cars    Multiple    If you own/lease a car(s), which brand are they?    Citroen     Citroen
12  17  Automotive  Make of car/cars    Multiple    If you own/lease a car(s), which brand are they?    Daihatsu    Daihatsu
13  17  Automotive  Make of car/cars    Multiple    If you own/lease a car(s), which brand are they?    Fiat    Fiat
14  17  Automotive  Make of car/cars    Multiple    If you own/lease a car(s), which brand are they?    Ford    Ford
15  17  Automotive  Make of car/cars    Multiple    If you own/lease a car(s), which brand are they?    Honda   Honda
16  17  Automotive  Make of car/cars    Multiple    If you own/lease a car(s), which brand are they?    Hyundai     Hyundai
...
```

E eu gostaria de obter algo do género:

```
    QID     Category    Text    QType   Question    Answer0     Answer1     Answer3     Answer4     Answer5     Answer6     Answer7     Answer8     Answer9     Answer10    Answer11     Answer12     ...      
4   16  Automotive  Access to car   Single  Do you have access to a car?    I own a car/cars    I lease/ have a company car     I have access to a car/cars     No, I don’t have access to a car/cars   Prefer not to say       
5   17  Automotive  Make of car/cars    Multiple    If you own/lease a car(s), which brand are they?    Audi    Alfa Romeo  BMW     Cadillac    Chevrolet   Chrysler    Citroen     ...
```

Posso combinar um **número dado/estático** de colunas cujo nome começa com o mesmo valor em Resposta e QID:

```
df = pd.DataFrame('path/to/file')

# lazy - want first of all attributes except QID and Answer columns
agg = {col:"first" for col in list(df.columns) if col!="QID" and "Answer" not in col}
# get a list of all answers in Answer0 for a QID
agg = {**agg, **{"Answer0":lambda s: list(s)}}

# helper function for row call.  not needed but makes more readable
def ans(r, i):
    return "" if i>=len(r["AnswerT"]) else r["AnswerT"][i]

# split list from aggregation back out into columns using assign
# rename Answer0 to AnserT from aggregation so that it can be referred to.  
# AnswerT drop it when don't want it any more
dfgrouped = df.groupby("QID").agg(agg).reset_index().rename(columns={"Answer0":"AnswerT"}).assign(
    Answer0=lambda dfa: dfa.apply(lambda r: ans(r, 0), axis=1),
    Answer1=lambda dfa: dfa.apply(lambda r: ans(r, 1), axis=1),
    Answer2=lambda dfa: dfa.apply(lambda r: ans(r, 2), axis=1),
    Answer3=lambda dfa: dfa.apply(lambda r: ans(r, 3), axis=1),
    Answer4=lambda dfa: dfa.apply(lambda r: ans(r, 4), axis=1),
    Answer5=lambda dfa: dfa.apply(lambda r: ans(r, 5), axis=1),
    Answer6=lambda dfa: dfa.apply(lambda r: ans(r, 6), axis=1),
).drop("AnswerT", axis=1)

print(dfgrouped.to_string(index=False))
```

Como posso combinar um **número dynamico** de colunas cujo nome começa com o mesmo valor em Answer e QID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opa,

Creio que com o exemplo mais abaixo você consiga desenrolar.

Respondendo especificamente parte de sua pergunta

> Como posso combinar um número dynamico de colunas cujo nome começa com o mesmo valor em Answer e QID?

A dificuldade é um número dinâmico de colunas, certo?

Sendo assim veja abaixo:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3,4], "B": [[1,2,3], ["A","B","C","D"], ["Z"], [8,8,8]]})

>>> df

   A             B
0  1     [1, 2, 3]
1  2  [A, B, C, D]
2  3           [Z]
3  4     [8, 8, 8]

>>> new_df = pd.DataFrame(df["B"].tolist(), index=df["A"])

>>> new_df

   0     1     2     3
A
1  1     2     3  None
2  A     B     C     D
3  Z  None  None  None
4  8     8     8  None
```

No seu caso, crie as listas com as repostas e depois associe à uma coluna de seu dataframe.

Espero que ajude.